# Angular 2 Checkbox preventDefault

Tags: checkbox, angular

I am making a Bootstrap checkbox dropdown and the options is wrapped in an `<a>` tag that handles the click, but I also have a `<input type="checkbox">` inside the a-tag.

My problem occurs when the user is pressing on the actual checkbox instead of just the `<a>` element. Both are clicked and some conflict happen. The checkbox checked-state should be inverted but isn't.

In Angular1 it worked to just use preventDefault() on the checkbox-click, but in my angular2-test it stops the checkbox from updating its state.

Need help with what I am doing wrong.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#option of options">
    <a href="" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" (click)="setSelected($event, option)">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected(option)" (click)="checkboxClick($event)" /> {{ option.name }}
    </a>
  </ul>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6D5GQ9mnaMALNnPzf5Na

I want the same behaviour when clicking on the checkboxes as clicking on the links to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check this. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/jyX1hGNlRk0dNsR0XMXU?p=preview

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#option of options">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" (click)="setSelected($event, option)">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected(option)" (keyup)="checkboxClick($event)" /> {{ option.name }}
            </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. So I suppose the solution was to drop the "preventDefault" from the <a click event and instead add # to href="" to make it work.

Answer (score 14):

Just add `;false` to the event handler expression. Returning false results in `preventDefault()`

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected(option)" (click)="checkboxClick($event);false" /> {{ option.name }}
```

You get the same effect if you return false in `checkboxClick()`

Comment: I thought that the preventDefault is default in angular2, isn't it?

Comment: This comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7277#issuecomment-188938815 addressed to you :D says "@eesdil atm, we preventDefault on every event that gets dispatched to the WebWorker here. I don't believe we're stopping propagation though." => events that get dispatched to WebWorker

Comment: Yes, I can see, thats right. Also checked the source code and they are checking the return value of the callback and not changing it. Memory...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `event.stopPropagation()`?
It is stopping the click to propagate from checkbox to the a click handler...