# How do I prevent a checkbox from looking selected if click handler causes error

Tags: angular

I want to prevent a checkbox from becoming selected if a handler bound to the click event encounters an error.  Here's a section of my component's HTML

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
  id="category-{{cat.id}}" value="{{cat.id}}"
  (click)="toggleCategory(cat)"
  [checked]="menuItem.hasCategory(cat.id)"
>
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2042 indicates that returning false from the `toggleCategory` method should work, and indeed it does:  clicking on the checkbox **does not** cause the checkbox to appear checked when `toggleCategory` looks like this:

```
toggleCategory(category:Category):boolean {
  return false;
}
```

However, the actual implementation of `toggleCategory` invokes an `HttpClient` POST, and so it's not known until later whether an error occurred.

I tried making `toggleCategory` return `Observable<boolean>` but that doesn't work.

```
toggleCategory(category:Category):Observable<boolean> {      
  return of(false);
}
```

I've seen [Angular 2 Checkbox preventDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017793/angular-2-checkbox-preventdefault) in which the accepted answer seems to suggest wrapping the <input> element in an <a> and handling the click event there.  This behaves the same way as clicking on the checkbox does for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to put the `MouseEvent` itself additionally to the `toggleCategory` as parameter:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleCategory($event, cat)">
```

And in `toggleCategory` the `$event.target` will be the `input` itself, and its `checked` porterty can be changed to the wished value. So if we want to prevent the checkbox to be checked, following code snippet can be used:

```
toggleCategory($event: MouseEvent, category: Category) {
   ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked = false;
}
```

The above example sets the checkbox always back. This code snippet can be in the error cases to prevent the checkbox selection.

Here is a stackblitz example, if you want to play around with it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-op51jp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I had already tried that, and the `cat` parameter sent to `toggleCategory` was being sent as undefined for some reason.  

I just tried it again to be sure, though, and it is working correctly.  I must have had a typo or something when I tried it the first time.

Thanks!