# Why checkbox is not controlled by variable?

Tags: angular

Why here i toggled the checkbox, it will be checked?

Why it is not controlled by the variable myVar1, i didn't set myVar1 to true on purpose to test.

I think it will always be unchecked, because i didn't set the myVar1 to true.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4lsc6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

component:

```
myVar1 = false;
```

template:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="myVar1"/> myVar1 {{myVar1}}
```

Comment: It works for me. After setting `myVar1` to true, the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @Tvde1 I want it always unchecked, if keep myVar1 always to false, i think the checkbox should be always unchecked

Comment: Set click to return a false:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017793/angular-2-checkbox-preventdefault

Comment: You want the checkbox to be readonly/disabled?

Comment: I want to the checkbox checked is only controlled by value of myVar1, no matter how user toggle the checkbox, if myVar1 is false, then it will not be checked, hope it's clear